# How do I resolve the generic for Realm's object observer?

Tags: swift, realm

I have implemented an object observer in Realm...

```
let contactObserver: NotificationToken = contact.observe { change in
    switch change {
    case .change(let object, _):
        guard let contact = object as? Contact,
...
```

The observer works fine. But you'll notice, in the `.change` case, that I'm casting the associated object to its actual type, `Contact`. I'd like to avoid that, if possible.

I notice that `observe` is a generic...

```
func observe<T>(keyPaths: [String]? = nil, on queue: DispatchQueue? = nil, _ block: @escaping (ObjectChange<T>) -> Void) -> NotificationToken where T : RLMObjectBase
```

I'm particularly confused by `(ObjectChange<T>)`. How do I resolve the generic in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You specify type for the generic constraint when you declare the closure parameter:

```
let contactObserver: NotificationToken = contact.observe { (change: ObjectChange<Contact>) in
    switch change {
    case .change(let object, let changes):
        print("change: \(object): \(changes)")
    case .deleted:
        print("deleted")
    case .error(let error):
        print("error: \(error)")
    }
}
```

The associated value in the `.change` case is now a `Contact`.